# use gradle to download ivy jar, but the jar name is wrong

Tags: gradle, ivy

I use gradle to download the ivy jars, gradle script like this:

```
repositories {
ivy {
    artifactPattern "http://mycompany/libs/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"

    ivyPattern "http://mycompany/libs/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile (
        "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4"           
)
```

}

and My ivy config like this:

```
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.4">
        <artifact name="slf4j-api-1.6.4" type="jar"/>
    </dependency>
```

the jar name on the ivy respository is :
http://my.company/his-libs/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4/**slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar**

but when I download them use gradle, the jar'name is :
D:\Users\myname.gradle\caches\artifacts-23\filestore\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.4\jar\bff73780230e6559b63134bbc2056c312eabb849\slf4j-api-1.6.4-1.6.4.jar

increase "-1.6.4" in the jar name. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ivy config has the version number in the artifact name. Gradle's dependency cache isn't Ivy based and will always construct the file name from the artifact name and version. You can't change this but can change the file name when, say, copying or packaging the artifact file.

Comment: Thank you very much. But have other way to solve it? Change file name is too trouble for me.

Comment: Unless you change the artifact name (which sounds like a good solution) or live with the current name, you'll have to rename the file. Note that you shouldn't rename the file in the cache but copy and rename it (with Gradle of course).

Comment: I think change the artifact name is a good idea.The artifact name on my company respository is confused and I real want to change it. Thanks.